# WTF moment in EasyMock API?? Is this logic even possible?

Tags: java, easymock

Today I came across this seemingly funny set of expectation setters in the Easymock API for
'and' expectations setters for `long`, `short`, `double`, `boolean`, ...

an example

```
public static long and(long first,
                   long second)

Expects a long that matches both given expectations.

Parameters:
    first - placeholder for the first expectation.
    second - placeholder for the second expectation. 
Returns:
    0.
```

Is this even possible?
How can a long, for example, be 1L AND 2L
The same wtf is true for `boolean`, `short`, `double`, `int`, ...

My mind is blown!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that to satisfy the general requirement of binary operators taking two parameters AND the ability to handle native types, that you end up with some extraneous conditions being tested.

So, these methods exist to make EasyMock regular, rather than to allow you to test that a long can hold two potentially contradictory values simultaneously.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the least

Comment: The EasyMock API is written to be regular and consistent, so you can AND or OR two expectations together and it just works. My assumption is that, as you can also use native types in the place of expectations, that the EasyMock authors naturally ended up writing methods that coped with two native types ANDed together for consistency with the ones that OR them together. It's a consequence of the API being regular rather than a design decision to allow you to test that one object has two distinct values.

Comment: OK, that sounds reasonable. 
It could have been better documented in the docs, though

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure it out and I'm still not sure how and(boolean, boolean) should work but this snippet shows the usage for and(long, long)

```
/** */
@Test
public void andCanBeUsedToCheckForRanges(){
    class A{
        void foo(Long arg){};
    }

    A a = createMock(A.class);
    a.foo(and(gt(5L), lt(7L)));

    replay(a);
    a.foo(6L);
    verify(a);
}
```